# loop and change all record numbers in Firebird database

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5

I have a database table with unique record numbers created with generator but because of error in code (setting generators) record numbers suddenly became large because many numbers are skipped. I would like to rewrite all record numbers starting with 1 and finish with total records number. With application it will take a lot of time. 
As I see from documentation for Firebird it should be simple task using loop but I have no experience with Firebird programming, I am using only simple SQL statements, can somebody help?

Comment: that is a misuse of generators, they are designed to produces out-of-transactions numbers, with gaps when transactions are rolled back or otherwise do not end with insert. // read PSQL tutorials, like Stored procedures. You may run them using "EXECUTE BLOCK", you need to declare internal integer variable, set it to zero, and make a "for select ... order by ID-column as [named cursor name]" loop with begin-end, there inside the loop you would "update ... set ID-column = :local-ID-variable where current of [named cursor name]" and then increment the variable.

Comment: then after the commit you would move the generator to the max ID. Notice: it would still take long, for it would de facto take COPYING of the entire table within the DB. Read corresponding topics here: https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25.html -  chapter 6 for `SELECT` (including FOR SELECT and "as cursor" clauses) and `UPDATE ... WHERE CURRENT OF` and PSQL variables and loops (chapter 7).

Comment: Thanks, I managed to create execute block, but as I commented in next solution, to much complicated. Anyway, I learned something :)

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is no need to program a loop, simple `update` statement should do. First, reset the generator:

```
SET GENERATOR my_GEN TO 0;
```

and then update all the records assigning them new id

```sql
update tab set recno = gen_id(my_GEN, 1) order by recno asc;
```

It assumes that all references to the `recno` field are via foreign key with `ON UPDATE CASCADE`, otherwise you either mess up your data or the update fails.

During this operation there should be no other users in the database!

That being said, you really shouldn't care about gaps in your record numbers.

Comment: It's elegant solution, but in my case it seems that any solution is complicated because I need to remove all constraints including primary key, which is not possible because it is used in foreign key definition... anyway as you said, its better to leave as it is. I worried about integer size (currently record number is over 10 000 000)   but I have time until 2,147,483,647 is reached :)

Comment: Now when I think about it you can't update them in random order, records must be updated in the "current id order", ie `update ... order by recno asc`. This way you don't try to assign an new id which is still in use (and thus fail), ie if you have record ids 1, 3,... then first your update would assign 1 to the record 1 (ie no change), then youd assign 2 to record 3 and so on.

Comment: @Danxy maybe you can change FK constraints into cascading ones instead. But, again, that is abuse of the very idea of generators... Thing also about out-of-the application references. Like your employer writes an e-mail to another employee talking about "document #12345". Week later someone deletes documents 12200-12250 and suddenly that referenced document gets re-numbered into 12295. Then the employee 2 reads thee-mail (or even paper snail-mail), opens the doc #12345 - and without knowing it works with unrelated different one.

Comment: ain, yes, you're right, It came to my mind later. I ordered by date column. 
Arioch, I don't expect to have such problems because relational table is just added, new in project... well, I will see what to do If I had extra time (which is almost unattainable wish:)

Comment: @Danxy If you're worried about integer sizes, I'd sooner suggest that you take steps to switch to using `BIGINT` (although that will be more complex and than just renumbering).